# Websockets alongside a python http server

Tags: python, http, websocket, backend, connexion

I'm trying to figure out the best architecture to support connections to thousands of websockets alongside a managing HTTP server.

I want to be able to manage all of the connections through the HTTP server with minimum complexity.

Ideally, I am trying to merge:

- An existing proprietary python library that uses the [`websockets`](https://pypi.org/project/websockets/) package
- A [`connexion`](https://pypi.org/project/connexion/) (Flask-OpenAPI) application framework

Can these parts fit together?

Also, could this run under a WSGI server gracefully or must I transition to ASGI?

Any assistance, tips or pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) where you can run multiple things at once. To start a thread it's simple just

```py
from threading import Thread

def testT1():
    for x in range(20):
        print("printing from testT1")

def testT2():
    for x in range(20):
        print("printing from testT2")

Thread(target=testT1).start()
Thread(target=testT2).start()
```

This might not be the best example. But basically it allows to run multiple things even if testT1 blocks it